# access to two global arrays?

Tags: php

How to access two global variables that store an array in themselves?
I want to output two arrays at the same time.

**It should be "12345" followed by "abcde"**

```
$number = [1,2,3,4,5];
$str = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
 
 
function twoMassive(){
    $names = ["number", "str"];
  
    foreach($names as $items){
        yield $GLOBALS[$items];   // according to the plan, the elements of the $number 
                                // array should come out first, and then $str
    }
};
 
 
foreach(twoMassive() as $items){
    echo $items;
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You don't use any `global` import for the variables. What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: ``fn () {
global $number; ...
}``

Comment: @NicoHaase OP is using `$GLOBALS` as alternative

Comment: @Justinas you got me - haven't worked with that in a while (for good reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yield from` to yield all values from your array:

```php
<?php

$number = [1,2,3,4,5];
$str = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
 
 
function twoMassive(){
    $names = ["number", "str"];
  
    foreach($names as $items){
        yield from $GLOBALS[$items];   // according to the plan, the elements of the $number 
                                // array should come out first, and then $str
    }
};
 
 
foreach(twoMassive() as $items){
    echo $items;
}
```

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=dZBNa8MwDIbvgfwHEXLowFDWbad2jO2yS8sOO5YeXEeeDbEVbGellPz3-SOlgzFhhCy9emxp8zKooa7qqrWjOaKDZ9jfsxV7YI_s6bCOeR9ysuENg-aYnEiuSw6bJIF85GhF0GQhnGjHvdffuLi7xFK01nKDPmPKM6k5gks7FJEkh1yoxSzmHlod0PgrJNlZY9-BdGSgfd9-vL1uP_dFdVjH8nIJXAhynbZfEAiCQhh6blmOsEeDNnggme_XkW_4_yxxneNn8IrG-AFBBoHGAFI7Hxhw2yWihbStgpvqarrtZh7t92r-DohC0ZyKndMP&v=8.1.11)

Comment: This code works fine.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Accept answer if it satisfies you